# Search Google Plus Public Posts

Tags: google-plus

Since one can make posts public, is it possible to search for say, all users who mentioned "Ponies" in their posts? Specifically I am looking for people who have posts pertaining to "My Little Pony"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the "Search" box in Google Plus. It's just to the right of the Stream/Photos/Circles/etc. bar.

https://plus.google.com/s/Ponies

You can further refine the search to just posts (in your circles and public posts) https://plus.google.com/s/Ponies/posts

Don't forget to use "Best of" / "Most recent" per your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Do a search on Google as follows:

> [site:plus.google.com My Little Pony](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aplus.google.com+My+Little+Pony)

Comment: That's fine as far as it goes, but it's not going to be limited to public posts. Other pages at that domain (say, the help documents) will also be part of the search.