# Search public images in Google Photos

Tags: google-plus, search, picasa-web-albums, google-photos

On Picasa Web Album, I can search all public photos via the explore features, for instance a search by tag: https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/view?feat=tags&psc=G&filter=0&tags=wikimania

(Note, Google is hiding such features more and more in an attempt to force people to use other services. If at some point in the URL gets redirected elsewhere, see [how it looks currently](https://archive.is/pzzNI).)

How do I do the same on Google Photos? https://photos.google.com/search/wikimania only finds my own photos with the word.

Google Plus doesn't provide a side access either: https://plus.google.com/s/wikimania/photos only finds (very few) *posts* with photos, while I only want the photos themselves and all of them.

There are other questions about [searching posts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18978/search-google-plus-public-posts) and [searching own photos](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/59684/search-picasaweb-google-photos-by-album-name). I also asked elswewhere [how to mark and search Creative Commons images](https://plus.google.com/111275098680181852126/posts/ZBD3vSWyvLw).

Answer (score 3):

## Short answer

As of October 29, 2023, Google Photos doesn't include a feature for searching public photos. Google+, Picasa Web Albums and the Album Archive have been retired.

## Explanation

Google Plus Photos and Picasa Web Albums have been retired.

Albums created in Google+ or Picasa Web Albums could be found in Google Photos, but Google Photos search doesn't include a search of photos shared by others publicly.

### Google announcements

From https://get.google.com/albumarchive, taken on October 29, 2023.

> Since July 19, 2023, Album Archive is no longer available. Ref.

- [Moving on from Picasa](https://googlephotos.blogspot.com/2016/02/moving-on-from-picasa.html), February 2, 2016, with updates on 2018. They are obsolete.

## Alternatives

- Use http://images.google.com
- Use http://www.google.com/imghp (Google Images homepage)

## References

- [Google Photos Help](http://support.google.com/photos)
- [Get started with Google Photos - Photos Help](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6142214?hl=en&ref_topic=6128818)
- [Create, find, & edit photo albums - Photos Help](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6128849?hl=en)
- [What's happening to Picasa, Picasa Web Albums, and the Picasa Web Albums API? | Picasa and Picasa Web Albums Help](https://support.google.com/picasa/answer/6383491)

Comment: Glad to learn they unredirected some things. Are all Google Plus/Photos public images also added to Picasa Web Albums? I feel the sync is only in place for people who previously used PWA, I'd like some solid concrete.

Comment: AFAIK Google+, Picasa Web Albums and Google Photos use the same photos repository.

Answer (score 1):

> All your photos, organized, and easy to find <sup>[source](https://www.google.com/photos/about/)</sup>

Google Photos is currently for your own photos. Your options are basically to use Picasa Web Albums Search, Google+ Search or Google Images Search.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Google Image Search:    https://www.google.com/imghp

Comment: @AlE. That looks to be a different question.

Comment: Yes, finding my own photos is nice but the question is mainly about public photos. I tried Google Search, but it either [finds nothing](https://www.google.it/search?q=wikimania+site:picasaweb.google.com&site=imghp&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X) (compared to an internal picasaweb search) or gives [completely unrelated stuff](https://www.google.it/search?q=wikimania+site:google.com&site=imghp&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X) especially when [setting a date](https://goo.gl/j4iBgr) ([nsfw example](https://goo.gl/utmTHm), avatar of a member of a G+ group containing the word).

Answer (score -1):

http://picasaweb.google.com/data/entry/api/user/example@gmail.com?alt=json

just replace example@gmail.com with any gmail address and a page will load with with links to the public photos and albums of that person. Just open second last link and there will all the public albums of photos shared by that gmail address.

Comment: This answer is obsolete as Picasa Web Album has been retired.